# how to add foreign keys in EF 7 alpha

Tags: entity-framework-core

How do I make a one-to-one relationship in EF 7 alpha3?

The old way of just defining navigation properties does not work, and the modelBuilder does not have the previously used HasRequired/HasOptional methods.

Can anyone shed some light on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until recently, there weren't any model builder APIs for defining relationships. Instead, you have to manipulate the underlying `modelBuilder.Model` object. Here is an example of a one-to-many relationship.

```cs
class Blog
{
    public Blog()
    {
        Posts = new List<Post>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}

class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Post>().ForeignKeys(x => x.ForeignKey<Blog>(p => p.BlogId));

        var model = builder.Model;
        var blog = model.GetEntityType(typeof(Blog));
        var post = model.GetEntityType(typeof(Post));
        var fk = post.ForeignKeys.Single(k => k.ReferencedEntityType == blog);
        blog.AddNavigation(new Navigation(fk, "Posts", pointsToPrincipal: false));
        post.AddNavigation(new Navigation(fk, "Blog", pointsToPrincipal: true));
    }
}
```

You can read more about our current (as of 2014-07-31) thinking for [what these APIs will look like](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Entity-Framework-Design-Meeting-Notes---July-31,-2014#code-first-relationship-api). The end result would look something like the following.

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
    .OneToMany(b => b.Posts, p => p.Blog).ForeignKey(b => b.BlogId);
```

Comment: I'm using EF7 beta3, and Entity doesn't not have the ForeignKeys-property. Also OneToMany, ManyToOne, One and Manya are still missing. Any other possibility to have a one to many / many to one relationship in EF7 currently?

Comment: I had some success using Entity<>().HasMany().WithOne().ForeignKey() -syntax. Even when that referenced parent model ("Blog") remained null, at least the custom foreign key (not "BlogId", but "SomethingOtherId") was kind of working. Previously I got "column "BlogId" not found error".

Comment: It's all gone. EF7 beta7.

Comment: @Shimmy Do you know where can I find those methods in EF7 beta7? I can not find it.

Answer (score 0):

With EF7 beta7, new set of methods are introduced for defining relationships between entities.

For one to many relationship,

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
   .Reference(typeof(Blog), "Blog")
   .InverseCollection("Posts")
   .ForeignKey(new string[] { "BlogId" });
```

With, `.Reference(typeof(Blog), "Blog")` relationship from Entity `Post` to `Blog` is configured. First arguament is the type of the entity that Post targets and second arguament is the name of the navigation property.

With, `.InverseCollection("Posts")`, one to many relationship is configured. Arguament to this function is the name of the navigation collection.

With, `.ForeignKey(new string[] { "BlogId" })`, foreign key is configured. If this foreign key is not set, then shadow foreign key is automatically generated for you.